# Error Handling with Alamofire in Swift 2

Tags: ios, error-handling, swift2, alamofire

Hi I am practising some code, my code is fine with `case .Success(let value):` and it is displaying alert but will `case .Failure(let error):` display alert with The 4xx class of status code?

```
  Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
            if let value = response.result.value {

             let json = JSON(value)

             switch response.result {
             case .Success(let value):

             let name = json["name"].string
             if let nothing = name {
             self.alertMessage(message: "Name not Found")
                    } else {
            self.alertMessage(message: "Name Found")
                    }
            case .Failure(let error):
            self.alertMessage(message: "Error 4xx / 5xx")
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `validate` to check status codes:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL)
    .validate()    // or, if you just want to check status codes, validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)

            if let name = json["name"].string {
                self.alertMessage(message: "Name Found: \(name)")
            } else {
                self.alertMessage(message: "Name not Found")
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            self.alertMessage(message: "Error 4xx / 5xx: \(error)")
        }
}
```

Or, in Swift 3:

```
Alamofire.request(url)
    .validate()    // or, if you just want to check status codes, validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)

            if let name = json["name"].string {
                self.alertMessage(message: "Name Found: \(name)")
            } else {
                self.alertMessage(message: "Name not Found")
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            self.alertMessage(message: "Error 4xx / 5xx: \(error)")
        }
}
```

Also note that you should probably move the examination of `response.result.value` to inside the `Success` section (or just grab the `value` passed there). Also, the determination of whether `name` is found was backwards.